# Could "avvertire" mean "to advise"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

[Word Reference](https://www.wordreference.com/iten/avvertire) says that "avvertire" can mean "to advise", but the meaning in the corresponding example provided by WR dictionary (La maestra ha avvertito mia madre dei miei pessimi voti) is different: "to inform". Is the former meaning really possible in that verb? If I understood [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/avvertire/) and [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/italian-english/avvertire) well, there is no such meaning in "avvertire".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree, this is a mistake in Word Reference. *Avvertire* does not mean anything similar to *advise*. I have signaled it to them (but feel free to do the same!).

Answer (score 4):

I would personally never use *avvertire* to mean *advise*. However, I don't think it is completely wrong either.

In the *Grande Dizionario della Lingua Italiana* one reads under [*avvertire*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI01/GDLI_01_ocr_905.pdf)

> 1. Ammonire, avvisare; far consapevole, edotto; **informare**.

I think that this last meaning is where the link appears. If one looks in the [*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/advise), one sees that one of the meanings of *advise* is

> [formal] to give someone official information about something.
>
> They were advised of their rights.

It might be a far-fetched hypothesis, but I suspect that this is what is intended on Word Reference.

Comment: I have to admit that I have never seen that meaning of "advise" before. Anyway, IMHO it shouldn't be in the list of the main translations of "avvertire", especially before "to inform" (one of the most usual translations).